# How to split a string in ANSI-SQL

Tags: sql, database, vectorwise, actian

How can I split a column value in ANSI SQL? I use VectorWise DB and **VW doesn't support split method**.

How can I solve it?

```
SELECT
       stars,
       LEFT(stars, POSITION(',', stars + ',') - 1) AS star1,
       CASE WHEN CHARACTER_LENGTH(oyuncu) - CHARACTER_LENGTH(REPLACE(stars, ',', '')) > 0
          THEN TRIM(SUBSTRING(stars, POSITION(',', stars) + 1,
              POSITION(',', stars + ',', POSITION(',', stars) + 1) 
              - POSITION(',', stars) - 1))
          ELSE NULL
          END AS star2,
       CASE WHEN CHARACTER_LENGTH(stars) - CHARACTER_LENGTH(REPLACE(stars, ',', '')) > 1
          THEN TRIM(SUBSTRING (stars, POSITION(',', stars + ',',
              POSITION(',', oyuncu) + 1) + 1, CHARACTER_LENGTH(stars)))
          ELSE NULL
       END AS star3
    FROM administrator.dnm
```

I added a screenshot a What I want after the changes. But I haven't got enough reputation for What I want after the changes :(

ANSI doesn't support some specific methods that T-SQL has.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://docs.actian.com , click on "Options", pick Actian Vector 3.5, and in the navigator pick the "Vector 3.5 SQL Language Guide".

The SUBSTR and SUBSTRING functions are explaned here: `Elements of SQL Statements -> SQL Functions -> String Functions -> SUBSTR Function` . Your example should work on Vector 3.5.